# Which is the trick to solve this simple equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Good evening,

I'm facing this equation:

$x=0.5\cdot10^{-3}(10-18\cdot10^{3}x)^{2}$

I know that I can find ther solution by putting in some equation calculator but I'm curious to find the trick to solve it numerically.

I've tried, but I'm lost in the lines.

Many thanks!

Comment: It is a quadratic equation. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

$$2000x=(10-18000x)^2$$and try using:$2000x=t$,
$t=(10-9t)^2$

Comment: Thanks, I obtained $t=(100+81t^{2}-180t)$

Comment: Use the quadratic formula and solve.